# display:inline-block isn't working

Tags: html, css

```css
.test,
.test2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="test">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button></div>

    <div class="test2">
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta odit omnis maiores quis, tempore ut dolorum iure, nesciunt dolores laboriosam cumque praesentium blanditiis porro repellat numquam. Ducimus, dolores atque accusantium!
      </span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/6270/

I have two divs which I would like to have placed next to each other.

Comment: it's working as it should, you either need to set a max-width or use flex

Comment: Since you are using bootstrap. You can replace your test and test2 class with something like col-sm-2 and col-sm-10 respectively. This will make thing easy and nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `display: flex;` to `.row` for this

http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/6277/

```css
.test, .test2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
.row {display: flex;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/flatly/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 
<div class="test">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button></div>

<div class="test2">
   <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta odit omnis maiores quis, tempore ut dolorum iure, nesciunt dolores laboriosam cumque praesentium blanditiis porro repellat numquam. Ducimus, dolores atque accusantium!
  </span>
</div>
   
</div>
</div>
```

> To know more about display property -
>   https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: I solved thank you. I tried display: flex but it did not work. The flex-wrap was the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you `.test2` div is not having a `max-width` or `width` property on it, the width of the second div is taken as the width of the screen to acomodate the text. Trying putting either of it on `.test2`. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems you are using bootstrap, So use bootstrap grid system.
>   I have used col-sm-2 & col-sm-10 classe, I have removed test & test2 classes

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button></div>

    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta odit omnis maiores quis, tempore ut dolorum iure, nesciunt dolores laboriosam cumque praesentium blanditiis porro repellat numquam. Ducimus, dolores atque accusantium!
      </span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```